# Update A Table With The Count Of Another Table With Complex Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

(Using SQL Server 2014)

I have two tables

```
1)  Vendors
a.      VendorName (PrimaryKey)
b.      ClientCount

2)  Payments
a.      VendorName (ForeignKey)
b.      ClientID
```

I want to update Vendors.ClientCount to the number of unique ClientID’s for that VendorName in Payments. I’m sure this is simple to do, but three hours of flailing about have convinced me I’m not simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
UPDATE Vendors 
SET ClientCount = (
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.ClientID) FROM Payments P WHERE P.VendorName = Vendors.VendorName 
)
```

Although this seems like something better calculated/computed on the fly rather than as a constant value.